# iOS - how do I create a "utility" class that all my controllers can call

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I am new to iOS and obective-c so I am not too sure how to best accomplish this seemingly simple task.

What I want is to make a class that looks like this in pseudocode:

```
class UtilityClass
{
    // Have a method that I can pass parameters to 
    String doCalculation ( String art1 , String arg2 )
    {
        return arg1 + arg2;
    }
}
```

My uncertainty is:

1) xCode seems to be inclined to lay out my file structure in a relatively flat way. So should I make a utils directory and have this file be under utils/fileName ? Usually I am kind of used to having at least some src directory, but so far I have not been prompted by anything to create one.
2) How do I import and call this class/function from my controllers?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: In some cases, is appropriate to use a Singleton Pattern: http://db-in.com/blog/2011/12/objective-c-singleton/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just create a new group called Utilities, and then create your class inside it. Like,

```
utils.h 
utils.m
```

Later in your ViewController's header file just add.

```
#import "utils.h"
```

if this utils class is used by many controllers in very fat project then, find a file called, Should be inside supporting files group.

```
YourAppName-Prefix.pch
```

In that file you have a code block like this,

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#endif
```

Just edit this block and add your `utils.h` reference here, In this way your entire project can create utils object without explicitly importing into their own header.

Edit like this.,

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
    #import "utils.h"
#endif
```

Comment: thanks, what is the common practice? To create the new group under something like maybe root_dir/src/utils ? I have been placing my controllers in the root directory which felt funky all along....what is a good way to lay out the directory structures here?

Comment: It's all depends on you, it is very flexible you may create group in anyway you want. Because while importing files you do not include those group name anyway. But I recommend to standardise your way of doing it and persist that for your next projects.

Answer (score 10):

First of all create a new File in Xcode and **uncheck** xib file. Name the Project as you like . and extend it from NSObject .

for creating static method you have to replace function starting - to + like

interface. class

```
@interface Utility : NSObject
+ (int)getNumber;
+ (void)setNumber:(int)number;
@end
```

.m class

```
#import "Utility.h"

@implementation Utility

static int number = 1;

+ (int)getNumber {
  return number;
}

+ (void)setNumber:(int)newNumber {
  number = newNumber;
}

+ (id)alloc {
  [NSException raise:@"Cannot be instantiated!" format:@"Static class 'ClassName' cannot be instantiated!"];
  return nil;
}

@end
```

call it in any other ViewController like

```
 NSLog(@"number = %d", [Utility getNumber]);
    [Utility setNumber:3];
    NSLog(@"number = %d", [Utility getNumber]);
```

[for details..](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/04/20/objective-c-create-a-static-class/)

Answer (score 4):

Where you store the files is up to you, just make sure XCode knows where to find them. The class itself should be made like any other Objective C class, just make it inherit from `NSObject` instead of one of the graphical classes:

```
// MyClass.h
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    int instanceVar;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) int property;
@end

// MyClass.m
#import "MyClass.h"
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize property;
-(id) init {
    ...
}
-(int) function  {
    ...
}
@end
```

To use the class in another file, just import the header like any other class

```
#import "MyClass.h"
```