# Do we have to create interface for Utility classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS and trying to understand the Objective-C world so that I can write idiomatic code. I come from Java background.

I want to create a utility class so that some static methods can be shared across view controllers. I saw this - [iOS - how do I create a "utility" class that all my controllers can call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479638/ios-how-do-i-create-a-utility-class-that-all-my-controllers-can-call) - which recommended creating an interface and implementation and import interface.

**Question:**

Is it recommended to create an interface every time? What advantage do I get than to write just implementation classes with bunch of static methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Interface" is different to an interface in Java. That would be a protocol in Objective-C.

The interface part makes the public parts of the class known to whoever uses it. You import the .h file (containing the interface) in your other classes that use your utility class, in order to make this class and methods knows to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, in Obj-C it's more common to have both a header and implementation file for all classes. However, it's not completely necessary when all your methods are static util methods. You could in fact put all your utility methods in a class
`Util.m`
then include it in each file where you need access to it's methods

```
#import "Util.m"
```

The one advantage i could see to having a .h file is that you then control what becomes public.
Any method signature included in the header file becomes public. Also, like the previous answer mentions, interfaces are quite different in Obj-C than java.

Comment: Importing a .m file causes multiple copies of the executable to be built into your program. Each #import duplicates code, which makes your program bigger. For small files used a few times it's not a big deal, but still not good practice. Get in the habit of creating .m/.h pairs and #import'ing the .h.

Comment: @DuncanC, thanks, learned something new today, any reference where I can learn more about it?

Comment: #include harks back to the original C precompiler. #import is a slight update (smart enough to only include a given header once for any given compile pass.) You can learn about the precompiler in the old standby Kerrigan and Richie C book. (And no doubt in many others. But the K&R is a must read for serious programmers in C-family languages)

Answer (score 0):

I coming of C# world and i searched many time how to reproduce the factory pattern. The key word @Interface is confusing at the beginning.

You can declare this. 
The directive OBJC_ROOT_CLASS inhibit compilation warning without NSObject heritage. You can Leave NSObject heritage but you pull with all NSObject message implementation. When you suppressing NSObject you cant instanciate your utilities class and only send messages to static methods.

MyClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol IMyClassProtocol

+ (void) methodOne;
+ (BOOL) methodWithReturn;

@end

OBJC_ROOT_CLASS
@interface MyClass <IMyClassProtocol>


@end
```

MyClass.m

```
#import "MyClass.h"
@implementation MyClass

+ (void) methodOne
{
}

+ (BOOL) methodWithReturn
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Using OBJC_ROOT_CLASS is going to cause lots of problems. Don't do that. Make all your objects inherit from NSObject.

Answer (score 0):

If you have commonly used functions, you can just declare them as functions. There is no need to generate an `@interface` or a class at all. For example, here is a common function from my projects:

```
# RNPaths.h
NSString *GetPathForDocument(NSString *fileName);

# RNPaths.m
NSString *GetPathForDocument(NSString *fileName) {
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];
  return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
}
```

Note that this is not called "Utility." It's called "Paths" because it includes functions for calculating paths (the "RN" is just my prefix). Similarly, I have an RNColor file (.h and and .m) with functions like:

```
UIColor *UIColorFromRGB(int rgbValue) {
  return [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
}
```

These are pure functions. They take an input and give an output, with no mutable state. There's no reason to create a class around them (and that would be confusing).

It would be reasonable to argue that they should be prefixed, but I find that a bit hard to read for my functions (and with static linking, it's been safe, which is one reason I favor static linking, even on Mac).

Now, in the case of my `UIColorFromRGB()`, you might prefer to create it as a category on `UIColor`, and that would be fine, too. But there'd still be no reason to create a new class for it. And there would never be a reason to call it "Utility."