# UITextView validation with code reusability

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview, nsregularexpression

Beginner here, hopefully a simple question about preventing code duplication.

If you have code that detects what is being typed in a `UITextView` (ie. regex for validation purposes), and you want that code  to apply to multiple `UITextView`'s on different screens, how do you go about doing that rather than just duplicating that code in each and every `UIViewController` that utilizes that `UITextView`?

i.e.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)textFieldshouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

Comment: Have a validation class method on some utility object.

Comment: Have a shared delegate?

Comment: @IanMacDonald, are you referring to the AppDelegate?

Comment: No, I'm referring to your `UITextField`'s delegate. If you assign the same object as a delegate to multiple `UITextField` objects, you will accomplish what you're requesting.

Comment: @jeffamaphone, do you mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658433/accessing-method-from-other-classes-objective-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479638/ios-how-do-i-create-a-utility-class-that-all-my-controllers-can-call

Essentially I would just create a helper method that I call inside each of my textFieldshouldChangeCharactersInRange methods right? That way I just import from the util each time, and call one line instead of having the same code in all my classes?

Comment: Something like that, yes.  You could also make a custom UIViewController category, for example.  There are a few different ways to accomplish this.

Comment: @IanMacDonald, not really sure I'm following...from what it sounds like, you're suggesting a way to make sure multiple `UITextField` objects all have the same validation based off of the delegates correct? If so, I don't think that would help since I'm looking for a way to use those same delegates on different `UIViewControllers` without having to copy/paste hundreds of lines of code. Unless I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class specifically for this purpose. If you need to do special `UITextFieldDelegate` stuff, you can either subclass this class or attach your own delegate to it.

```
@interface TextValidationDelegate : NSObject <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak) id<UITextFieldDelegate> delegate;
@end

@implementation TextValidationDelegate
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
  BOOL acceptable = YES;
  // TODO: Calculate acceptability.
  // ...

  if (acceptable && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)]) {
    acceptable = [self.delegate textField:textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:range replacementString:string];
  }

  return acceptable;
}

// TODO: Override other UITextFieldDelegate methods and pass through to self.delegate when it respondsToSelector.
@end
```